How do I make my Snakemake Snakefile automatically generate a report?
I have built a pipeline in Snakemake. This pipeline has rules to process data (for example, a rule that creates output.txt). I want to be able to run the pipeline like so:
snakemake --cores 1 files/output.txt
Doing this works. I can generate a report on this file by running:
snakemake --report report.html files/output.txt
I am making this pipeline to be used by others, so I am hoping to have this report be generated without having to run a second command. I do not know what files my users my ask my pipeline to make, so I cannot simply put a line in my Snakefile that says "on success, run snakemake --report etc.."
Is there any other way to have my Snakefile generate this report automatically?
I have looked in every form of documentation I could but I cannot find any way to do this in the Snakefile or in associated configuration files. If I could access the name of the requested file that my user calls Snakemake to make on the command line, then I could generate this report like below, but I do not know what that file is:
onsuccess:     shell("snakemake --report report.html " + str(requested_file))
I have also looked into the source code of the snakemake Python object, the workflow.persistence Python object, and the workflow.persistence.dag object; I was able to use the latter to generate a DAG by writing it to a file, but I cannot seem to access the last file of that DAG from the object, and there is no documentation I can find on any of these objects that would explain how to use their many attributes.
